# Processing of xml data inside coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8, coldbox

After processing data I can able to set the xml value

```
<cfoutput>#xmlResults#</cfoutput>
```

output example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shiporder orderid="889923"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
    <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
    <shipto>
        <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
        <address>Langgt 23</address>
        <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
        <country>Norway</country>
    </shipto>
    <item>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <note>Special Edition</note>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <price>10.90</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <price>9.90</price>
    </item>
</shiporder>
```

How I can use the details separately using coldfusion ?(I want to use the title value inside my application.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<cfsavecontent variable="variable.xmlResults">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shiporder orderid="889923"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
    <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
    <shipto>
        <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
        <address>Langgt 23</address>
        <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
        <country>Norway</country>
    </shipto>
    <item>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <note>Special Edition</note>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <price>10.90</price>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <quantity>1</quantity>
        <price>9.90</price>
    </item>
</shiporder>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfset variables.myXmlArray = xmlparse(trim(variable.xmlResults))>

<cfset variables.responseNodesItem = XMLSearch(variables.myXmlArray,"//*[ local-name() = 'item' ]") />
<cfset variables.title = variables.responseNodesItem[1].title["XmlText"]> 
<cfdump var="#variables.myXmlArray#">
<cfdump var="#variables.responseNodesItem#">
<cfdump var="#variables.title#">
<cfabort>
```

Answer (score 2):

After parsing, you can use XPath to [search](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78e8.html), and/or refer to elements in the xml document directly:

```
<cfset doc = XmlParse(xmlResults)>
<cfloop index="node" array="#XmlSearch(doc, '//item')#">
    <p>
        #node.title.xmlText#
    </p>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: thanks .if <item> having different tag inside then what will do?

Comment: The above code will crash if <item> does not have a title element in it. You would do well to make sure it exists before referring to it directly.

Comment: If I try to access <note> values, what will happen? it is not in the second <item>.

Answer (score 2):

You probably know the format of the xml and you can loop over the items

```
<cfset xmlParsed = xmlparse(xmlResults) >

<cfoutput>

<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(xmlParsed.shiporder.item)#" index="i">   

        title: #xmlParsed.shiporder.item[i].title.xmltext#<br>      

        <cfif structkeyExists(xmlParsed.shiporder.item[i],"note")>
            note: #xmlParsed.shiporder.item[i].note# <br> 
        </cfif>     

        <br>
</cfloop>

</cfoutput>
```